# Sign in with Facebook error code: 1349195 [ IONIC ]

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem a few days ago with Ionic and the login with Facebook.

I have everything included, install the respective Ionic plugin and I put the APP_ID and the APP_NAME.

When I'm in the APP, and I want to log in with Facebook, Pop-up appears normally. When I give to accept for facebook to access my personal data and my e-mail this happens:

> "Facebook error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: The hash of
>   the key does not match any of the stored key hashes. Go to
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android for get
>   more information. [extra]: "

I did not find any way to solve it.

Comment: Are you running your app debug mode? Did you add key hash to facebook ?

Comment: Yes I add Hash key to facebook. In two sides, developer options and android.

And...how to run my app in debug mode?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem

Download your APK to your PC in java `jdk\bin` folder

in my case `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_121\bin`

Go to java `jdk\bin` folder and run cmd then
copy the following command in your cmd

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk
```

Copy the SHA1 value to your clipboard
like this `CD:A1:EA:A3:5C:5C:68:FB:FA:0A:6B:E5:5A:72:64:DD:26:8D:44:84`
and open http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php to convert your SHA1 value to base64.
This is what Facebook requires
get the generated hash `********************=` and copy the key hash to the facebook app.

Comment: Hello @Mayank,  where I placed the generated hash code in my application?

Comment: @RashedShaon In Settings->Basic->Key Hashes

Comment: If you are debugging an Ionic Application, the generated apk is located in platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\

Comment: I'm using Unity and this answer also helped me, thanks.

Comment: Please mention where to put this hash in FB app.

Comment: great . thank you. your answer is save my time.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, and I noticed that I put the wrong password when creating the hash code.
the correct password is: **android**

Comment: Wouldn't that be your own password?

Comment: No, here you have to use the default password : android

Answer (score 0):

Go in https://developers.facebook.com/

```
- My Apps and Facebook Login and do the quick start steps and at step 4
- Add your Development and Relases Key Hash you will need to run in cmd or bash depend on your OS , a comand and type password: android
and after that , you will recive a hash code.
- Copy this hash code in Settings->Basic at hash code section.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it solves it using this openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip, before I was using this other openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip and it brought me problems, but now it works fine with this openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip !!!

https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

```
C:\...bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\pathuser\.android\debug.keystore | C:\openSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openSSL\bin\openssl base64
```

Answer (score 0):

try to connect with facebook, than go to the android studio console -> put on verbose -> search hash ,
then you will find the hash that you need to put on fb developer console -> settings -> basic -> android

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is making the next steps:

- run command for mac: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`
- then the terminal asks me for a password and writes: `android` <-- important
- and for end copy hash and paste to Facebook developer kind of:

  [https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[YOUR_APP_ID]/fb-login/quickstart/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%5BYOUR_APP_ID%5D/fb-login/quickstart/)

[image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did everything that is described in the Facebook documentation and therefore was at a loss why the clearly executed actions described in the documentation did not lead to the desired result. The answer above by **Mayank R Jain** ended up helping me.
The only thing I can add is that you can not do such complex actions with generating APK, uploading it to jdk\bin folder, then generating SHA-1 using keytool. It is enough to get the SHA-1 fingerprint using Gradle in Android Studio (see screenshot) and then use the base64 converter http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php - the result will be the same.

[SHA-1 generation with Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIJvu.png)